# django not finding app

Tags: python, django

I am getting a import error in django. My main urls.py settings file is located at `main/main/urls.py` my module or app is located here `main/apps/builder/urls.py`.

traceback error

```
ImportError at /
No module named apps.builder.urls
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    ***************
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named apps.builder.urls
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in     import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python26
Python Version: 2.6.0
Python Path:    
['/home/pycode/main',
 '/usr/lib/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 12 Jun 2012 12:39:17 -0500
```

main/main/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('main.apps.builder.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Try with just 'apps.builder.urls' or 'main.main.apps.builder.urls' and see I guess it's got to do with the way you have laid out your applications. Also ensure that you have __init__.py in all folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `apps` module must be below `main/main` or you have to make sure your `apps` folder is in your `sys.path`, probably best to set PYTHONPATH.

Comment: could i just move my `apps` folder into `main/main` and change my urls.py to `url(r'^$', include('apps.builder.urls')),`

Comment: or everytime you run your server you can do 
`sudo PYTHONPATH=<yourpath> python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2):

Did you add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py file?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps

also as ramdaz suggested each directory needs a `__init__.py` file even if it is empty.

Comment: yes i added it to installed apps in main/main/settings.py as `apps.builder` and yes all my directories have `__init__.py`